# How to view my local database name in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to find what my local database name is, as it isn't directly stated in my settings file. This is what I have currently listed.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default='sqlite:////{0}'.format(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'))
    )
}
```

I don't want to change anything because I am a bit freaked out it will change anything I already have. Any way to do this through something like the shell?

Comment: `db.sqlite3` is your database name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config should look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
}
```

As you can see, your database name is `db.sqlite3`.

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't recognize the format I was using